optimization spending time from order time to arrival time of passengers in static ride sharing systems
this is explain all my question:
Suppose, for example, you have a passenger transport company. Like Snap, but you saw that Snap only travels for one request. The problem is that a driver can carry as many passengers as the capacity of his car at the same time. For example, the capacity of the car is 4 people. For example, drivers patrol the city from 8 am to 8 pm. A list of requests has already been sent to the company. For example, we have 10 requests. Arrange them in order of time. Each request includes one person. That means we need exactly one empty seat to serve a request. So, maximum 4 requests can be in the car at the same time. These travel requests also have a specific origin. They have a specific destination and a time window, for example [8, 9], this means that this request can get on the car from 8 o'clock and must reach its desired destination before 9 o'clock.
If we have a directed and weighted graph where each point shows a place and the path between these points shows the time required to travel from each point to the next point.
The objective function should be in such a way that we have the best allocation of passengers to drivers, so that the travel time for passengers from the moment their request is registered (for our example, the passenger can board from 8 am) until the moment they reach their destination is at least
Now, the model that we need and the code that we need should take into account all of this, how and in what order it will pass through which points and which passengers are better on its route. In addition, if there is boarding and disembarking at each step, the capacity of the car seats should be taken into account, for example, if two requests are inside the car at the moment of passing through a point, then these two seats are left empty and they may ride in the next points. New arrivals and departures will also happen. That is, in each stage, by passing through each point, the capacity of the car must be updated.
In addition to this, when it is doing the minimization of the time, the routing of the shortest path is definitely done.
In fact, we want this company to give a specific program list to its vehicles every day, from morning to night when they are at work, where to go and which places to pass and which requests to take in the vehicle, and the traffic and these are currently zero. Let's take a look. For example, when we say that the travel time from point one to point two is 10 minutes. Exactly the same ten minutes are needed and at every point it is possible to know what time the driver reached which point.
Because the origin of the driver may not be exactly the same as the origin of the passenger. For example, the driver may arrive at the origin of his first request at 8:10 and pick him up and....
Now our code should solve the simplest case of this problem. For example, two means of transport are located at different origins. There is no need to go back to their original source, and there are 10 to 20 different requests with specific parameters, for example, their list. These requests should be assigned to those vehicles...
so i have problem in modeling and after that in coding of this problem in python. here is my code but i don't khnow is that true or not? and how can i complete it?
from pulp import *
import networkx as nx
from networkx import shortest_path_length

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
D = ['driver1', 'driver2'] 
R = ['rider1', 'rider2', 'rider3','rider4','rider5','rider6','rider7','rider8','rider9','rider10']
V = ['location1', 'location2', 'location3', 'location4', 'location5', 'location6', 'location7', 'location8', 'location9', 'location10'] 
G = nx.DiGraph()
edges = {
    ('location1', 'location2'): 10, 
    ('location2', 'location3'): 12, 
    ('location3', 'location4'): 15,
    ('location4', 'location8'): 10,
    ('location8', 'location6'): 10,
    ('location6', 'location5'): 10,
    ('location8', 'location10'): 10,
    ('location1', 'location5'): 10,
    ('location4', 'location1'): 10,
    ('location5', 'location8'): 10,
    ('location10', 'location9'): 10,
    ('location1', 'location4'): 10, 
    ('location2', 'location5'): 10, 
    ('location8', 'location2'): 10,
    ('location7', 'location8'): 10,
    ('location7', 'location2'): 5,
    ('location8', 'location3'): 12,
    ('location6', 'location9'): 5,
    ('location8', 'location9'): 10,
    ('location1', 'location8'): 10,
    ('location4', 'location5'): 10,
    ('location5', 'location10'): 20,
    ('location10', 'location7'): 15,
    ('location1', 'location9'): 10,
    ('location5', 'location9'): 10,
    ('location5', 'location9'): 5,
    ('location1', 'location2'): 5,
    ('location2', 'location8'): 2,
    ('location8', 'location3'): 3
}

G.add_weighted_edges_from((u, v, w) for (u, v), w in edges.items())
#origine of riders 
vsr = {'rider1': 'location1', 'rider2': 'location2', 'rider3': 'location3', 'rider4': 'location2', 'rider5': 'location5', 'rider6': 'location7','rider7': 'location1', 'rider8': 'location2', 'rider9': 'location6','rider10': 'location8'} 
#destination od riders
ver = {'rider1': 'location4', 'rider2': 'location5', 'rider3': 'location6', 'rider4': 'location5', 'rider5': 'location7', 'rider6': 'location10','rider7': 'location10', 'rider8': 'location5', 'rider9': 'location8','rider10': 'location10'} 
num_people = {'rider1': 1, 'rider2': 2, 'rider3': 1 ,'rider4': 2,'rider5':1,'rider6':2 ,'rider7':2,'rider8':3,'rider9':2,'rider10':1}
ved = {'driver1': ['location1'],
      'driver2': ['location2']}
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, node_color='lightblue', node_size=1500)
labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=labels)
shortest_paths = dict(nx.all_pairs_dijkstra_path(G))
shortest_path_lengths = dict(nx.all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length(G))
stv_v_prime = {}
dv_v_prime = {}
for v, lengths in shortest_path_lengths.items():
    for v_prime, length in lengths.items():
        dv_v_prime[(v, v_prime)] = length

for v, lengths in shortest_path_lengths.items():
    for v_prime, length in lengths.items():
        stv_v_prime[(v, v_prime)] = (length * 5) / 60
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, node_color='lightblue', node_size=1500)
labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=labels)
dvsr_ver = {}
for rider in R:
    start_location = vsr[rider]
    end_location = ver[rider]
    shortest_distance = dv_v_prime[(start_location, end_location)]
    dvsr_ver[rider] = {'shortest_distance for individual trip': shortest_distance}
#start work time of drivers and time window for each riders . first time od riders is the ordered rime
etd={'driver1': 8, 'driver2': 8}
ltd={'driver1': 24, 'driver2': 24}

etr = {'rider1': 8, 'rider2': 8, 'rider3': 8, 'rider4':9,'rider5':9,'rider6':9,'rider7': 10,'rider8':10,'rider9':9,'rider10':9} 
ltr = {'rider1': 24, 'rider2': 10, 'rider3': 10, 'rider4':24,'rider5':24,'rider6':18,'rider7': 12,'rider8':15,'rider9':20,'rider10':24} 
# max car capacity 
qd = {'driver1': 4, 'driver2': 4}
M = 1000
prob = LpProblem("Ride_Sharing_Problem", LpMinimize)

default_distance = 0 
yd_r = LpVariable.dicts("match", ((d, r) for d in D for r in R), 0, 1, LpBinary)
td_v = LpVariable.dicts("departure_time", ((d, v) for d in D for v in V), etd[d], ltd[d], LpContinuous)
z_r = LpVariable.dicts("served_rider", (r for r in R), 0, 1, LpBinary)
x_dij = LpVariable.dicts("path", (D, V, V), cat='Binary')
od_v = LpVariable.dicts("car_occupancy", ((d, v) for d in D for v in V), 0, num_people[r], LpInteger)
prob += lpSum([yd_r[d, r] * dvsr_ver[r].get('shortest_distance', default_distance) for d in D ]) + lpSum(z_r[r] * x_dij)

for d in D:
    for r in R:
        prob += yd_r[d, r] <= int(vsr[r] and ver[r] )
        prob += yd_r[d, r] <= int(etr[r] >= etd[d] and ltr[r] <= ltd[d])
for r in R:
    prob += lpSum(yd_r[d, r] for d in D) <= 1    
    prob += lpSum(yd_r[d, r] for d in D) == z_r[r]
    
for d in D:
    for r in R:
        prob += lpSum(yd_r[d, r] for r in R if etr[r] < etd[d] or ltr[r] > ltd[d]) == 0
      
for d in D:
     for v in V:
        prob += od_v[d, v] <= qd[d]    
for d in D:
    prob += lpSum(yd_r[d, r] * num_people[r] for r in R) <= qd[d]    
for d in D:
    for v in V:
        if v in predπd_v:
            prob += od_v[d, v] == od_v[d, predπd_v[v]] + lpSum(yd_r[d, r] * num_people[r] for r in startsπd_v[v]) - lpSum(yd_r[d, r] * num_people[r] for r in endsπd_v[v])
for d in D:
    for r in R:
        prob += yd_r[d, r] * etr[r] <= td_v[d, vsr[r]]
        prob += M - td_v[d, ver[r]] >= (M - ltr[r]) * yd_r[d, r]
time_window = 1                  
for d in D:
     for v in V:
        if v in predπd_v:
           
           prob += td_v[d, v] >= td_v[d, predπd_v[v]] + stv_v_prime[(predπd_v[v], v)]

prob.solve(CPLEX_PY())
for v in prob.variables():
    print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)
    #print("Objective:", value(model.objective))
    print("Objective:", value(prob.objective))


how can i consider arrival driver time to rider's origine?
how can i optimized rider's order time to arrival time to their destination?
and how can i show that riders should share their trip with others if time window be ok?
and how we can give the program work time for each day?
anyone can help me?
